# No material on objects in linked group?

Tags: materials, linked-data, groups

I took a few meshes and armatures, and placed it in a group. Then I opened a new blend and linked the group. Now all materials are gray, and it looks black on rendering.

I tried to add a proxy, and that works for animating the armature, but there is still no material.

Why is that? When I tried the same thing with a simple red box, it works. However I can see the materials used in the linked file when I look at materials for another object. However if I try to use them on the default cube, it doesn't seem to work.

Any help appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using the same render engine in both files ? Are there any lights in your scene

Comment: Ahh I'm pretty sure the default is internal and the linked is cycles. Stupid mistake! I'll change the startup file to cycles. Thanks!!:)

Answer (score 1):

Change the render engine to the same as the source file, in this case **Cycles**, instead of Blender Render which is the default for new scenes. (Thanks to Duarte Farrajota Ramos)